# Baggage allowance with Air-Philippines from Manila - Ozamiz and Economy Supersaver ticket?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, philippines, philippine-airlines

I have a flight ticket from Manila to Ozamiz flying with Philippine Airlines. The ticket class is `Economy Supersaver`.
On [this link](https://www.skyscanner.com.ph/news/tips/philippine-airlines-baggage-allowance-guide-for-pinoys) I read that for a PAL domestic flight I can check in a piece of luggage of maximum 20kg. 
However, on the [company's site](https://www.philippineairlines.com/en/ph/home/TravelInformation/BeforeYouFly/BaggageInformation/BaggageAllowance/BaggageAllowanceandFees/DomesticFlights) I read that for this class it's 0kg.

Still, the `Free Baggage Allowance` (25kg) seems like something which applies to all tickets.

So which of those can I bring for check-in? 0, 15, 20, 25kg ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend going with what the airline says, 0 kg. After all, it is the official site and other sites may not be accurate or have up to date information.

When doing a flight search between those two destinations on their official website I also got an allowance of 0 kg.

Comment: Thanks, there was indeed no baggage allowed so I had to pay for mine.